# apt-offline for either offline or online system (mariadb 10.2 install)

Tags: apt, package-management, mariadb, apt-cache

I have a case where a product update may be done on either an internet-connected or **non-internet** connected 14.0.4 system. As part of the product update, it needs to switch from mysql to mariadb, version 10.2.

But, I need to install mariadb-server **10.2**, not 5.5 which is the default in 14.0.4.

I have not been able to get the apt-offline process to work if the target system happens to be internet-connected. It constantly goes for the 5.5 version.

I have created the .sig file, then the .zip file, then did an install of the .zip file on the target system using "apt-offline".

However... when I go to "apt-get install mariadb-server", it wants to only, ever install the 5.5 version. I have tried *so* many things, like:

> sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.2.7

and various other version strings. I have tried:

> sudo apt-get install /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

but that generates a bunch of

> E: Unable to locate package /var/cache/apt/archives

errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try [downloads.mariadb.org](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/)

Choose your Distro, Release, MariaDB version and mirror there and follow the steps

To quote, "Here are the commands", with mirror site modified, "to run to install MariaDB on your Ubuntu system:"

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://your-mirror-of-choice/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu trusty main'`
```

"Once the key is imported and the repository added you can install MariaDB with:"

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Hope this helps you get started by installing 10.2 on your internet-connected 14.04. Then you may try your apt-offline process again.